# Translating for loop to method signature for hashmap printing

Tags: java, methods, printing, hashmap

I am able to print the hashmap using using the for loop in the main method, but I don't know how to transform that into a hashmap printing method. I'm confused about the method signature and incorporating it appropriately into the for loop.

```
        //Add Student object to hashmap 
        HashMap<Integer, Student> s= new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
        s.put(1,student1);
        s.put(2,student2);
        s.put(3,student3);
        s.put(4,student4);
        s.put(5,student5);
        
        //For loop printer for hashmap
        System.out.println();
        for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Student> m : s.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getValue());
            System.out.println();
        }

    // Print method for hashmap
    private static void printingMap(HashMap.Entry<Integer, Student> s){
        for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Student> m : s.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(m.getValue());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a method to `printMap` should take a `Map` (not a single `Map.Entry`). Like,

```
private static void printingMap(Map<Integer, Student> s){
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Student> m : s.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(m.getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And then

```
printingMap(s);
```

to call it. Don't forget to override `toString` in `Student`.

Comment: That works. I spent a few hours pouring over different examples and nothing. I only kind of understand what's going on in the code.